# Unable to create new site localhost:9001/yacceleratorstorefront/?site=jewellery-us

Tags: spring-mvc, catalog, sap-commerce-cloud, storefront

I am trying to create my own site in hybris 5.3.0.0. I have configured facet search, base store, catalog and version configuration same as apparel default site.
Still getting following error as in image.

Can anyone please suggest how to initiate default site in hybris.

[image: Error Screenshot]

Comment: Have you configured the WCMS site? If yes, did you assign an URL pattern to it?

Comment: Can you paste the stacktrace?

Comment: My URL Pattern : 
(?i)^http?://[^/]+(/[^?]*)?\?(.*\&)?(site=jewellery-us)(|\&.*)$

Answer (score 0):

1. Whenever you will hit the URL - localhost:9001/yacceleratorstorefront/?site=jewellery-us
   Request will go to `HomePageController` with Request Mapping as `@RequestMapping("/")`
2. `storeCmsPageInModel(model, getContentPageForLabelOrId(null));
   setUpMetaDataForContentPage(model, getContentPageForLabelOrId(null));
   updatePageTitle(model, getContentPageForLabelOrId(null));`

As you will find null here, it means system will look ContentPage with homepage flag TRUE in your active content catalog.

3. Please debug getContentPageForLabelOrId() method.
4. There may be a chance you don't have homePageJewellaryUS.jsp in correct path.

Please share your impex as well where you have created your HomePage so that i can exactly know the problem.

Comment: Thank you once again, i will check your suggestion for 1,2,& 3.

My assumptions are based on apparel-us/apparel-uk, so i can configure new site with required details and configurations.